# PhpStorm Code Generation is not inserting proper new line for generated code

Tags: phpstorm

All of a sudden my PhpStorm has stopped responding the `Code Style > Code Generation` configurations in settings.

I want generated code for constructor as below

```php
    /** @var string $keyFileLocation */
    protected string $keyFileLocation;

    /**
     * CalendarClientService constructor.
     * @param Config $config
     * @param Container $sessionContainer
     * @param ServiceAccountCredentials $serviceAccountCredentials
     */
    public function __construct(
        Config $config,
        Container $sessionContainer,
        ServiceAccountCredentials $serviceAccountCredentials
    ) {
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->sessionContainer = $sessionContainer;
        $this->serviceAccountCredentials = $serviceAccountCredentials;
    }
```

but I get this instead:

```php
    /** @var string $keyFileLocation */
    protected string $keyFileLocation;/**
* CalendarClientService constructor.
* @param Config $config
* @param Container $sessionContainer
* @param ServiceAccountCredentials $serviceAccountCredentials
*/public function __construct(Config $config,Container $sessionContainer,ServiceAccountCredentials $serviceAccountCredentials) {$this->config=$config;
$this->sessionContainer=$sessionContainer;
$this->serviceAccountCredentials=$serviceAccountCredentials;}
```

It was working fine earlier and I don't think I've changed anything.

`File >> File Properties >> Line Separator` configuration tried with both `\n` and `\r\n` alternatively.

`Settings >> Editor >> Code Style >> Line Separator` is set to `\n`

Below is the code for `Settings >> Editor >> File and Code Templates >> PHP Constructor`

```
#if (${PARAM_DOC} != "" || ${THROWS_DOC} != "" || ${CLASS_NAME} != "")
/**
${CLASS_NAME} constructor.
${PARAM_DOC}
${THROWS_DOC}
*/
#end
public function __construct(${PARAM_LIST}) {${BODY}}
```

**NOTE**

This was working fine yesterday and its happening with all insertions for `Code Generation` and `PHPDocs`. `Settings >> Editor >> CodeStyle` is configured to use `PSR12` and <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> fixes all other formatting issues except this one. I assume the main culprit is `new line`.

Comment: Have you tried it on a fresh new project?
I would suggest to export your code style and submit a new YouTrack issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: Thanks. That resolved the issue. I've created a fresh project and cloned from git. Looks like something corrupted the project's `new line` configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fresh project and cloned the Git. This resolved the issue. It looks like the `new line` configuration got somehow corrupted and failed to reset it.